# Multidigit ranges of files in lexicographical order in zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I would like to specify a range of files (in lexicographical order) with two integers (e.g. 2 to 57) in zsh by globbing.

For example: "pick the files 2 to 57 in lexicographical order under the path that matches some globbing pattern".

I thought using square brackets would do it

```
 for x in /foo/bar/*[2-57]; do print $x; done
```

but zsh apparently thinks I am asking for the files `2` to `5` (or something like that) instead of files `2` to `57`. Any thoughts why? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`[2-57]` is a character set consisting of `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `7`, in zsh and every other wildcard and regexp syntax out there. Your glob pattern `*[2-57]` matches every filename whose last character is one of those five digits.

I think you are misremembering the syntax of the `[m,n]` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Glob qualifiers always go in parentheses at the end of the pattern, and the range separator is a comma. The pattern `*([2,57])` expands to the 2nd, 3rd, …, 57th matches. The default expansion order is lexicographic (with some special magic to sort numbers in numeric order if the `numeric_glob_sort` option is set); you can control it with the `o` or `O` glob qualifier (e.g. `*(om[2,57])` to match the 57 most recent file except the one most recent file).

```
for x in /foo/bar/*([2,57]); do print $x; done
```

Not what you asked for, but related and possibly useful to future readers: if you want to enumerate files 2 to 57 whether they exist or not, you can use a range [brace expression](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion). This feature also exists in bash and ksh.

```
echo hello{2..57}
```

And if you want to match files whose name contains a number between 2 and 57, you can use the pattern `<2-57>`. This is specific to zsh.

```
$ ls
file1 file2 file3 file57 file58
$ echo file<2-57>
file2 file3 file57
```

Note that a pattern like `*<2-57>` is likely not to do what you expect, because the `*` could match digits too. For example, `file58` matches `*<2-57>`, with `file5` matching the `*` part and `8` matching the `<2-57>` part. The pattern `*[^0-9]<2-57>` avoids this issue.

Comment: You are right. I was misremembering the glob qualifier. Thanks for the careful explanation.

Comment: By the way, this statement got me a bit confused: `if you want to enumerate files 2 to 57 whether they exist or not, you can use a range brace expression`. If the files don't exist and there are no matches, how would the brace expansion know how to expand? (how would it expand differently from the glob qualifier?)

Comment: @intrpc `foo{8..11}bar` expands to `foo8bar foo9bar foo10bar foo11bar`. This bit of expansion is unrelated to file names. Similarly, `foo{eight,nine,ten,eleven}bar` expands to `fooeightbar fooninebar footenbar fooelevenbar`. This is [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) in ksh/bash/zsh.

Answer (score 6):

> but zsh apparently thinks I am asking for the files 2 to 5 (or something like that) instead of files 2 to 57. Any thoughts why?

Because `[]` brackets indicate a list of matched *characters* (which can be digits), not *numbers* interpreted mathematically. Such pattern is matched against a *single* character. The list can contain ranges, but of digits or letters. `[2-57]` match expands to *"All digits in the range from 2 to 5 **and** a 7"*.

To match numbers from 2 to 57, it would be easier to use a *sequence expression* instead of a globbing pattern (or together with such):

```
for x in /foo/bar/*{2..57}; do print $x; done
```

*Edit*: But this, unfortunately, will not give you lexicographical order of all listed files - they'd be grouped by common number endings due to shell expansion.

Comment: Thanks @rozcietrzewiacz! I should have thought about that. My files had numbers in them, so for a moment I thought `[]` was printing things in order..

Comment: Your explanation of `[2-57]` is correct, but I don't think `{2..57}` (that's what you meant, right?) is relevant to what intrpc wants to do, which is “pick the files 2 to 57 in lexicographical order”.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (time to go to sleep, I guess). And you're right - I'd forgotten about the *lexicographical order* part.