# Numerically ordered inputs to ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a directory full of ordered jpg files like so:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
.
.
.
265.jpg
```

On Windows, I could combine these files *consecutively, in order* into a file `scan.pdf` using

`magick %d.jpg[1-n] scan.pdf`

where `n` is the total number of jpgs (in my case, 265). On MacOS, using `zsh`, I tried this and received an error '`no matches found: %d.jpg[1-n]`' (again substituting `n`). If I instead try

`magick *.jpg scan.pdf`

it does not render in the correct order ([apparently](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/7060#discussioncomment-8212066), because it is in alphabetical rather than numeric order). Additionally, attempting

`magick [1-n].jpg scan.pdf`

doesn't seem to work for `n` > 9. What is the correct way to combine multiple consecutively named files in ImageMagick on MacOS (and presumably Linux)?

Comment: Which shell are you using, and what is the error message? Does the behavior change if you use quotes to prevent possible expansion by your shell, i.e. `'%d.jpg[1-265]'`

Comment: What about `magick {1..265}.jpg scan.pdf` ?

Comment: @JimL that works and is super clean! for some reason i assumed that syntax would end up re-running the command 265 times for each file rather than working correctly

Comment: @steeldriver post updated with shell info and error output. the quotes fixed it! was the issue that %d has its own interpretation in zsh overriding the input to magick, and the quotes help prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` and `[1-n]` are `imagemagick` extensions: the 1st is a filename reference and the 2nd a frame/image range - see section [Input Filename](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#input) in the documentation. That very section contains examples and a paragraph emphasized in cyan:

> Linux shells generally interpret brackets so we enclosed the filename
> in quotes above. In a Windows command shell the brackets are not
> interpreted but using quotes doesn't hurt. However, in most cases the
> roles of single-quotes and double-quotes are reversed with respect to
> Linux and Windows, so Windows users should usually try double-quotes
> where we display single-quotes, and vice versa.
> `magick 'images.gif[0-3]' images.mng`

Using `%d.jpg[1-256]` unquoted results in the shell expanding it to `%d.jpg1`, `%d.jpg2`,`%d.jpg5` and `%d.jpg6` (read [the answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24910) for an explanation) and since there are no such file names you get the `no matches found` error.
The obvious fix is to quote the expression, as per the manual, so that the shell passes it literally to the `magick` command:

```
magick '%d.jpg[1-256]' scan.pdf
```

It's worth mentioning that your shell, `zsh`, has the ability to sort globs numerically via the `(n)` glob qualifier so the following should also work:

```
magick ./*.jpg(n) scan.pdf
```

though this will process all `.jpg` files in the current directory (sorted numerically). If you want to restrict the expansion to a certain numerical range use the glob operator `<m-n>` which matches *any* number in the range `m` to `n`, inclusive:

```
magick <1-256>.jpg(n) scan.pdf
```